# How do I fix flatpak remote errors?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, flatpak

I installed flatpak via the command lines on their website and then proceeded to add the remote repository as instructed, but when I try to install something it says to specify a remote. I was trying to install inkscape from flathub.

Here are the command lines I used:

```
sudo flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

*I also tried without sudo*

To download the ref file:

```
wget https://www.flathub.org/apps/details/org.videolan.VLC
```

To install:

```
 flatpak install org.videolan.VLC
```

Error Message:

```
error: REMOTE and REF must be specified
```

Comment: I think question and answer should be moved to https://askubuntu.com

Comment: [Related question](https://superuser.com/questions/1755709/getting-this-error-when-trying-to-use-flatpak-no-remote-refs-found-similar-to)

Answer (score 11):

Try:

> flatpak install **flathub** org.videolan.VLC

"flathub" is the name of the missing REMOTE you added in your first step.